# Teradata Sql, trying to achieve rate of interest

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I was trying to achieve the below result:

[image]

The logic for the 1st row is, ((470-375)/375)*100
If someone has idea about this please contribute.

Comment: Please clarify is the question you are asking.
Are you attempting to replicate the logic to the other rows? or the logic does not work for one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `lead()` to retrieve the `cumulative_excp` of the next record, and then use it in the computation:

```
select 
    run_date, 
    cumulative_excp,
    100.0 
        * (lead(cumulative_excp) over(order by run_date) - cumulative_excp) 
        / cumulative_excp interest
from mytable
```